# Azure DevOps sign-in failing with AADSTS900144, and dev.azure.com Sign In routs to Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops

First issue, signing in to *dev.azure.com* no longer works like it used to?  In the past, there was a link to *sign in to Azure DevOps*.  This link is no longer on the page, and when using the *Sign In* option in the upper right corner, I'm routed to the Azure portal, not ADO.  What is the correct landing page for ADO login?

Second issue, if I do get to the login page (e.g., either by entering the org directly in the url like *dev.azure.com/MyTestOrg* or by clicking a link in an ADO alert email), I will often get this error:  *AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'code'*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.For logging to Azure DevOps issue, it is suggested you can first clear the cache, then try this link: [My Information](https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-US) first by following the step select your affected tenant -> select the affected organization, then login your organization.

[image]

2.For logging to Azure Portal, try this link:  [Home - Microsoft Azure](https://portal.azure.com/#home) with the affected user account.

3.For the issue situation above, check **whether your user account is also a Github user**, if so, it is suggested that you should first  **unlink** your GitHub account from the affected user.

You can follow the steps below to **unlink** your GitHub account from the affected user.

`Step 1`: Unlink your GitHub account from your MSA:
·

- Navigate to https://account.microsoft.com/security
- Select the **Advanced Security Options** tile and then look for the
  "Ways to prove who you are" section

This will list all the authentication options for your MSA

- From this list, find and expand the **Sign in with GitHub option**,
  select **Remove**, and then confirm

  You may be prompted to create a new password
  [image]

`Step 2`: After the operation1 above completed, then let the PCA or Org owner try deleting the affected user from the organization, and then try adding it to the org again, after successfully adding it, then **check in the Email box firstly to see whether received an invitation email** of Azure DevOps as below **with your affected user account**.

Then copy the inviting link and open it **in InPrivate mode with Edge or Chrome browser** with affected user account to login the org to see whether if it works.